# Installation error

Tags: installation

Can't install on the production side... Please see error below:

```
2014/11/29 16:16:38 [warning] [application] 404 - 
2014/11/29 16:16:38 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:765
Stack trace:
#0 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(194): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/index.php(35): CApplication->run()
#3 /home/saveandl/public_html/saveandlearn/index.php(14): require_once('/home/saveandl/...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/
---

******************************************************************************************************
2014/11/29 16:18:33 [warning] [application] Skipping record /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/records/BaseRecord.php because it’s abstract or an interface.
2014/11/29 16:18:33 [error] [system.db.CDbCommand] CDbCommand::execute() failed: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'craft_assetfiles' already exists. The SQL statement executed was: CREATE TABLE `craft_assetfiles` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `sourceId` INT(11) NULL,
    `folderId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `filename` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `kind` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "unknown",
    `width` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NULL,
    `height` SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NULL,
    `size` INT(11) UNSIGNED NULL,
    `dateModified` datetime NULL,
    `dateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
    `dateUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
    `uid` CHAR(36) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDb DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci.
2014/11/29 16:18:34 [error] [exception.CDbException] exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'craft_assetfiles' already exists' in /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php:358
Stack trace:
#0 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(1324): CDbCommand->execute()
#1 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/etc/db/DbCommand.php(481): CDbCommand->createTable('craft_assetfile...', Array, NULL)
#2 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/records/BaseRecord.php(296): Craft\DbCommand->createTable('assetfiles', Array, NULL, false)
#3 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/services/InstallService.php(167): Craft\BaseRecord->createTable()
#4 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/services/InstallService.php(56): Craft\InstallService->_createTablesFromRecords(Array)
#5 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/controllers/InstallController.php(159): Craft\InstallService->run(Array)
#6 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\InstallController->actionInstall()
#7 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#8 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#9 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#10 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('install')
#11 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(876): CWebApplication->runController('install/install')
#12 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(749): Craft\WebApp->_processActionRequest()
#13 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(194): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#14 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#15 /home/saveandl/public_html/craft/app/index.php(35): CApplication->run()
#16 /home/saveandl/public_html/saveandlearn/index.php(14): require_once('/home/saveandl/...')
#17 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/index.php/admin/actions/install/install
HTTP_REFERER=http://saveandlearn.fami.com.ph/admin/install
---

******************************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

Without digging too deep into what's going on here...

It looks like you're trying to install Craft into a database which already contains some tables. I say that because of lines like this:

```
CDbCommand::execute() failed: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'craft_assetfiles' already exists.
```

I would recommend dropping *every* "craft_" table in your database, and starting over.

If that doesn't work, I'd then replace your `/app` folder with a brand new copy... make sure the entire folder is FTP'd properly.

Finally, if neither of those suggestions work, I'd contact Pixel & Tonic directly (support@buildwithcraft.com), since you may have stumbled across an obscure bug or weird system configuration issue.